# How to put border rounded in DropdownButtonFormField? using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to put border rounded in DropdownButtonFormField? and how to make background color in the dropdown icon? please see the picture below

```
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: (globals.screenWidth * 0.8),
                height: (globals.screenHeight * 0.08),
                color: Colors.white,
         
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: globals.fontsize_18,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                  value: _selectedLocation,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedLocation = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: _locations.map((location) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: new Text(location),
                      value: location,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )
              )
```

result

[image]

this is i want result

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make rounded border for dropdownbutton in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150219/how-to-make-rounded-border-for-dropdownbutton-in-flutter)

Comment: Have a look here also if you want the items to be rounded too. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135853/how-to-create-a-rounded-corner-of-dropdownbuttonformfield-flutter/66136823#66136823] Spoiler: You will not use a `DropdownMenuButton` but a `PopupMenuButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it!

```
Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: (globals.screenWidth * 0.8),
                height: (globals.screenHeight * 0.08),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: globals.fontsize_18,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                  value: _selectedLocation,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedLocation = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: _locations.map((location) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: new Text(location),
                      value: location,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )
              )
```

Add this to DropdownButtonFormField

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                icon: Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down, color: Colors.white,),
                ),
            ),
```

Comment: hmm i get now the border, but how about the dropdown icon? how can i make it black?

Comment: @Rene try adding iconEnabledColor: inside DropdownButtonFormField

Comment: iconEnabledColor changes icon color, not its background

Comment: @TDN have you seen my `i want result`  ? picture?

Comment: oh im sorry, wrap the icon with container, i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a `PopupMenuButton` that allows a configuration of the menu items too.

[image]

### Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _selected = useState(locations[0]);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff1b2052),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Where do you want to go today?',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32.0,
                color: Colors.white54,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 48.0),
            MyDropdown<String>(
              items: locations,
              selected: _selected.value,
              onChanged: (newLocation) => _selected.value = newLocation,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDropdown<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<T> items;
  final T selected;
  final ValueChanged<T> onChanged;

  const MyDropdown({Key key, this.items, this.selected, this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
        onSelected: onChanged,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context) {
          return items
              .map(
                (value) => PopupMenuItem(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value.toString()),
                ),
              )
              .toList();
        },
        offset: Offset(1, 1),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('Location: ${selected}'),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  child: Icon(Icons.expand_more, color: Colors.white54),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

final List<String> locations = [
  'Earth',
  'Jupiter',
  'Mars',
  'Mercury',
  'Neptune',
  'Saturn',
  'Uranus',
  'Venus',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are answers here that work but do not answer the real question. There are multiple types of flutter drop down menu widgets. This question is about the DropdownButtonFormField widget.  This widget has a feature that makes it stand out from the rest.  It includes the option to add a labelText and InputDecoration. And it does not need to be nested into a Container widget to show a border.
It might have a bug because I needed to use ebabledBorder attribute vs. just the border attribute to get the border to work properly. As far as working with the icon I guess you can follow the container method cause I am unsure about icons.

> ```
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
>       value: _selectedItem,
>       decoration: InputDecoration(
>         labelText: widget.fieldName,
>         enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
>           borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 4),
>           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
>             Radius.circular(16.0),
>           ),
>         ),
>         focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
>           borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 4),
>           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
>             Radius.circular(40.0),
>           ),
>         ),
>       ),
>       onChanged: (value) {
>         setState(() {
>           _selectedItem = value;
>           widget.onChanged(value);
>         });
>       },
>       items: widget.items.map((item) {
>         return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
>           value: item,
>           child: Text(item),
>         );
>       }).toList(),
>     );
>   }
> ```