# Custom Decoration for DropDown Flutter

Tags: flutter

can anyone help me get the same style from these textField to my DropDown widget ?

This is the textField widget

```
TextFormField(
        obscureText: obscureText,
        controller: controller,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 12),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800], width: 2.0),
            )),
        validator: validator),
```

and this my DropDown :

```
DropdownButton(
                    value: professionChoosed,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        professionChoosed = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: professionList.map((valueItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: valueItem,
                        child: Text(valueItem),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
```

This is a preview of the simulator :
[simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnoBg.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150219/how-to-make-rounded-border-for-dropdownbutton-in-flutter                                                                                                                               https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRr1j.png

Comment: which type of decoration do you want ?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil ,  I want to add a label above and make the drop down the same width as previous inputs

Comment: @AnmolMishra yes I've done the rounded corners but still can't make the width same as the other inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DropdownButtonFormField instead of DropdownButton

```
     DropdownButtonFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 12),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800], width: 2.0),
                )),
                    value: professionChoosed,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        professionChoosed = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: professionList.map((valueItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: valueItem,
                        child: Text(valueItem),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
```

Comment: This is amazing but I guess it should be "new" instead of "const" on line 2.

Comment: "const" is there because values provided in InputDecoration are not dynamic they are constant(static).
also mark as answer if you found this useful.  Thanks

Comment: Good, one last question, how can I change the text color of selected option?

Comment: It's done . I just added this style:TextStyle(color: Colors.white). Thank you for your help.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use DropdownButtonFormField2 from my DropdownButton2 package. It's the same as DropdownButtonFormField but more customizable and have steady dropdown menu below the button. Give it a try!

**Package:** [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. refer official documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) for dropdown

```
 InputDecorator(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: dropdownValue,
        isDense: true,
        isExpanded: true,
        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue!;
          });
        },
        items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Your Result Screen -> [image]

Comment: Thank you . I went for the solution above. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome @LearningCode enjoy coding with flutter