# How to increase white space in between the text and the arrow in a DropdownButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
DropdownButton(
  value: dropDownValue1,
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropDownValue1 = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: <String>[
    'Work At Office',
    'Work From Home',
  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

how to increase space between the arrow and the text

[image: Now]

I hope I can make it be like this, how to do it?

[image: Desired output]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question. It is just a question I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `isExpanded: true,` under the dropdown for expanding icon

```
DropdownButton(
  isExpanded: true, // here need to change
  value: dropDownValue1,
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropDownValue1 = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: <String>[
    'Work At Office',
    'Work From Home',
  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69942179/13997210) also

Declare one variable for dropdown:

```
var dropdownValue = 'Work At Office';
```

Your widget

```
InputDecorator(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          isDense: true,
          isExpanded: true,
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = newValue!;
            });
          },
          items: <String>[
            'Work At Office',
            'Work From Home',
          ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: thank you too, what does `InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),` and `isDense: true` do

Comment: @RenSword The `InputDecoration` is used for border, labels, icons, and styles of the text fields and other things and 'isDense' means it reduce or remove the button height. you can refer `InputDecoration` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html) and Dropdown `isDense` also [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)